# Nous vs Noos in English

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, contemporary-english, greek

While searching online I found that ***nous*** is a Greek term that means intellect, intelligence, mind...etc. Also, in some sources, I found that ***noos*** is an alternative spelling of nous.

Is ***"nous"*** considered an English word and whether the alternative spelling and pronunciation ***"noos"*** understood by English speakers and not confused with noose?

Comment: *Noos* would probably be taken as a phonetic representation of the (incorrect to British ears) American pronunciation of *news*. Use *nous*. It's understood by people who study philosophy, and if you're not writing about philosophy, why do you want to use it?

Comment: I found it on Wiktionary https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noos#English

Comment: It seems that [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Greek+nous%2C+the+Greek+noos&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Greek%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Greek%20noos%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20Greek%20nous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Greek%20noos%3B%2Cc0) shows that it indeed occasionally spelled *noos*.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to try to use a term like that if one's only contact with it has been that one has 'found it on Wiktionary'. *Nous* is a term that is rich in associations for those who are familiar with how it has actually been used, and it is likely to breed confusion if one uses it without understanding what these associations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Nous*** is listed in dictionaries such as [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=nous%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB976GB976&oq=nous&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0i433i512l2j46i433i512j46i175i199i512l2j0i512j46i175i199i512j0i512l2.3062j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nous), and [Cambridge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nous), so it is definitely used in English. The most common pronunciation is

> /naʊs/

but as you can see in the link of the M-W, the same spelling ***nous***, can be pronounced in a way similar to the corresponding Greek word *νοῦς*:

> /nuːs/ 
> <sub>(Note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous) lists this pronunciation as *US*)</sub>

It does sound like *noose*, but then so many words sound the same. It is probably in the Wikipedia article that you found the alternative ***noos***:

> The Christian New Testament makes mention of the ***nous*** or ***noos***, generally translated in modern English as "mind", but also showing a link to God's will or law.

***Noos*** is not listed in dictionaries, and is better avoided. It looks strange and I can only think that it must be misspelled in this way to allegedly match the original pronunciation /nuːs/ or is borrowed mistakenly from the ancient genitive of the Greek *νοῦς - **νοός***.

Comment: Yes, your last quote from Wikipedia is where I found the word noos used explicitly. Thanks for your detailed answer, @fev.